# El administrador de conexiones 'FLATFILE' no está correctamente instalado en este equipo SSIS

Tags: visual, studio, ssis

estoy creando un proyecto SSIS para cargar datos de un archivo plano a un servidor, pero cuando intento crear la conexión con un archivo plano (o cualquier otro tipo de conexión) me aparece el mensaje del título. he intentado de todo pensando que tal vez dejé algo mal instalado, hasta formateé el equipo y nada sirve, he intentado buscar información del error pero no encuentro como solucionarlo. El error me apareció después de hacer una nueva instalación de visual studio y SSIS.

lo único similar que he encontrado es un artículo del 2014 con el mismo problema donde la solución era instalar service pack 1 para sql server 2014 lo hice por las dudas pero tampoco funcionó.
https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/topic/kb2969781-error-al-agregar-un-administrador-de-conexiones-personalizado-en-el-dise%C3%B1ador-2014-de-ssis-0a7a52a7-5f56-f9f3-f83d-72ec357a52b4

## Detalle del error:

No se pudo crear el nuevo administrador de conexiones. (Microsoft Visual Studio)

===================================

El administrador de conexiones 'FLATFILE' no está correctamente instalado en este equipo. (Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Design)

---

Para obtener ayuda, haga clic en: https://go.microsoft.com:80/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%C2%AE%20Visual%20Studio%C2%AE&ProdVer=17.8.34316.72&EvtSrc=Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Design.SR&EvtID=ConnectionManagerNotInstalled&LinkId=20476

---

Ubicación del programa:

en Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Design.DtsBasePackageDesigner.GetConnectionInfo(String creationName, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
en Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Design.DtsConnectionService.CreateConnection(String connectionType, ConnectionManagerUIArgs connectionUIArg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reinstalé SQL Server, al parecer el error iba por ese lado y no por la instalación de visual ni de SSIS. Con eso se solucionó.